# Please rerun biber?

Tags: biber

im using overleaf. Today when i logged into my document i had 100 yellow warnings, all for my references. the first warning reads:

"Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file: output and rerun LaTeX afterwards."

How do i rerun biber?

My code is for bib is:

```
    \usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Kilder.bib}
´´´
```

```
 @online{traeinfo,
author = "Træinformation",
title = "kursusmateriale om clt",
url = "https://www.traeinfo.dk/kursusmateriale-om-clt/"
addendum = "Besøgt: 01.05.2020",,
keywords = "Træinformation"
}
```

Ive found the faulty reference. whenever i remove it, my document is fine. it gives an error in the addendum, but i cant see why?

Comment: Ive found the faulty reference. whenever i remove it, my document is fine. it gives an error in the addendum, but i cant see why?

```
     @online{traeinfo,
    author = "Træinformation",
    title = "kursusmateriale om clt",
    url = "https://www.traeinfo.dk/kursusmateriale-om-clt/"
    addendum = "Besøgt: 01.05.2020",,
    keywords = "Træinformation"
    }´
´´´

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problematic entry

```
@online{traeinfo,
  author   = "Træinformation",
  title    = "kursusmateriale om clt",
  url      = "traeinfo.dk/kursusmateriale-om-clt"
  addendum = "Besøgt: 01.05.2020",,
  keywords = "Træinformation"
}
```

has two commas after the `addendum` field, but none after the `url`.

The contents of each field must be terminated with a comma `,`. That comma can be omitted for the very last field of an entry. (Though I still recommend you include it even then.)

Make it read

```
@online{traeinfo,
  author   = "Træinformation",
  title    = "kursusmateriale om clt",
  url      = "traeinfo.dk/kursusmateriale-om-clt",
  addendum = "Besøgt: 01.05.2020",
  keywords = "Træinformation",
}
```

or even better

```
@online{traeinfo,
  author   = {Træinformation},
  title    = {kursusmateriale om clt},
  url      = {http://www.traeinfo.dk/kursusmateriale-om-clt/},
  urldate  = {2020-05-01},
  keywords = {Træinformation},
}
```

---

The answer to

> How do I rerun Biber (on Overleaf)?

Is: You don't (– Overleaf does that automatically for you (by using the awesome `latexmk`). **But** a Biber run may not finish successfully or may not contain all cited references in case the are errors in your entries. So if you get a warning like

```
Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file
```

on Overleaf, check the other warnings and messages listed in the warnings/error area and see if there is something pointing to Biber and your `.bib` files.

If your `.bib` file and your `.tex` file are free of errors, Overleaf will run LaTeX and Biber for you automatically as often as required until you get a stable output.

In very specific circumstances you may get stuck with nasty errors, in that case it may help to delete the cache and recompile from scratch, see https://overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache

Comment: thanks a lot, it worked!

Comment: @MortenMandsberg If the answer helped you, you may want to consider upvoting it and/or accepting it by clicking on the green checkmark on the top left. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.